# Selecting elements from a list with non compatible length

Tags: r, extract, nested-lists, purrr

Given the following structure of the list:

```
x <- list(list(Main = list(one = list(tlv = 1, beta = 2), two = "three", three = 4,list_a = list(list(value_1 = "a1", value_2 = "b", c = "c")))),
      list(Main = list(one = list(tlv = 2, beta = 6), two = "seven", three = 8,list_a = list(list(value_1 = "aa2", value_2 = "bb", c = "cc")))),
      list(Main = list(one = list(tlv = 3),list_a = list(list(value_1 = c("aaa3", "aaaa4"), value_2 = c("bbb", "bbbb"), c = c("ccc", "ccc"))))))
```

I'm trying to create a dataframe with a structure like this:

```
tlv | value_1  
  1 | a1       
  2 | aa2      
  3 | aaa3     
  3 | aaaa4
```

so far I have to the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble::tibble(
  tlv = map(x, list(1,1,"tlv"), .default = NA) %>% unlist(),
  value = map(x, list(1,"list_a", 1, "value"), .default = NA) %>% unlist())
```

Which leads to the following error:

```
Error: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
 * Size 3: Existing data.
 * Size 4: Column `value`.
 i Only values of size one are recycled.
```

This makes sense given the structure of the list (3 values for one of the variables en 4 values for the other). But I don't see a solution to link the values to the parent element of the list. So that every 'value' also gets the corresponding 'tlv' value. Any guidance how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, this does the trick:

```
  x %>%
  map_df(~tibble(
          tlv = .$Main$one$tlv,
          value = .$Main$list_a[[1]]$value_1))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative :

```
library(tidyverse)

value_1 <-
  map_depth(x, 4, pluck, "value_1", .ragged = TRUE) %>%
  map(unlist, use.names = FALSE)

tlv  <-
  map_depth(x, 3, pluck, "tlv") %>%
  map_dbl(unlist, use.names = FALSE)

df <-
  tibble(tlv = tlv, value_1 = value_1) %>%
  unnest_auto(col = value_1)
```